# pig: how can I extract a tuple with all characters in a chararray?

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have a tuple with my_string = '12345', I want to turn it into this tuple: ('1','2','3','4','5').

Tried: `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(my_string, '(.)')` and got only (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Replace to turn it into (1,2,3,4,5,6).

```
REPLACE(my_string,'(?<!^)(.)',',$1');
```

Comment: great! actually, what I really needed was to break it to a tuple with those characters but it's a minor change: `TOKENIZE(REPLACE(my_string,'(?<!^)(.)',',$1'),',')`